# Is there a modifier that will add a exra thickness on every wall of an object?

Tags: modifiers

I have an object and I need to add a little extra thickness on every wall. 
The result must be a bigger object that will completely cover the original smaller object.

Is there a modifier that can help me do this automatically?
The resize option is not working because the object also contains circles and when I resize it the diametre is also resized and the final result no longer surrounds the original object.

I attached a blender file where I have 2 objects:

- NPN that is the original object
- NPN BIG that is the original NPN resized with a ratio of 1.054168634411929

The result is a bigger object that does not surround the original object.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the Solidify modifier?

Comment: Displacement Modifier?

Comment: I just tried Solidify, I increased the thickness but it doesn't seem to do the right thing on my object

Comment: I think Displacement modifier does the job, thank you.

Comment: ... Sometimes, all faces selected, Alt-S scale along normals?

Comment: Thank you, this works also.